# Reverting change gitbash, how to tell gitbash the commit message is finished

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I accidentally pushed to the wrong branch so I am reverting my changes.  I did a HARD revert and it came up with the list of files to be changed but asked for my commit message.  I typed it in but when I hit enter it just goes to the next line.  How do I tell gitbash that is the end of my message.  I already tried single and double quotes.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "HARD revert" and what command did you actually run here?

Comment: oops I meant HEAD, I ran git revert HEAD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did a HARD revert **and it came up with the list of files to be changed but asked for my commit message.** [emphasis added]

That was a text editor.

The text editor is probably Vim or Nano. To save and close in Vim, type `:wq`. To save and close in Nano, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> and choose <kbd>y</kbd> at the prompt.

To see what editor Git is using, run `git config --get core.editor`.